# Syntax to pass block to '[]' ruby method

Tags: ruby, syntax

Given a module `Bam`, and assuming that method `Bam.[]` is defined, the `[]` method can be called with a block in non-syntax sugar form like:

```
Bam.[]('boom') do |a|
  puts a
end
```

How can I call the `[]` method with a block in syntax sugar form `Bam['boom']`?

I tried the following:

```
Bam['boom'] do |a|
  puts a
end

Bam['boom'] {|a|
  puts a
}
```

They raise a syntax error.

I'm not looking for naming alternatives to `[]`. Ruby provides nice syntactic sugar, so I prefer `[]` over other names.

Comment: Ruby's syntax is flexible, but it has limits. You've pushed it too far here.

Answer (score 3):

`[]` is a shortcut, and it may not be designed to accept blocks.

Either use a traditional method (which in this case is only 1 char longer):

```
module Bam
  def self.get(a)
    yield a
  end
end

Bam.get('boom') do |a|
  puts a
end
```

or the explicit method syntax `Bam.[]('boom')`.

I assume yours is only an example, as the original method definition doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of is Ruby's `&` operator to [convert a proc to a block](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Proc+to+Block+Conversion):

```
block = proc { |a| puts a }
Bam['boom', &block]
```

Or without a variable:

```
Bam['boom', &proc { |a| puts a }]
```